# Do Ragna's powers come from his 32 years of training, or does the failed blood ritual to be transformed into a superior dragon have to do with it?

Tags: ragna-crimson

The Ragna Wikia states that Ragna's powers come from the knowledge and experience of more than 32 years of relentlessly hunting dragons from his future self.

But it also mentions that Ragna inherited the failed blood ritual to be transformed into a superior dragon by Ultimatia from his future self. Even though it failed some traces are left thus he is considered partially a member of the Winged Bloodline by selective powers unbeknownst to anyone

Do Ragna's powers come only from his 32 years of training, or does the failed blood ritual to be transformed into a superior dragon have something to do with it?